# Algebras determined by their globals

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, universal-algebra, magmas

If $A= (A, f_1, f_2, ...f_n)$ is an algebra, then its global (sometimes referred to as complex algebras) $\mathcal{U}(A)$ is defined on the power set $\wp(A)$ in the usual way.

It is known that $\mathcal{U}(A) \cong \mathcal{U}(B)$ implies $A\cong B$ for the class of finite mono-unary algebras (Drapal 1985). For which other classes of algebras (esp groupoids) is the result true?

A. Drápal, Globals of unary algebras, Czechoslovak Math. J. 35(110) (1985),
52–58.

Comment: Is there a link/reference to the "usual" definition of a the global algebra of an algebra?

Comment: @YCor I believe the domain is $\mathcal P(A)$, and all operations are applied set-wise: $f(X_1,\dots,X_k)=\{f(x_1,\dots,x_k):x_1\in X_1,\dots,x_k\in X_k\}$.

Comment: +1 The link to the paper is https://dml.cz/handle/10338.dmlcz/101996  (the Czech Digital Math Library has a large archive).

Answer (score 2):

**For which other classes of algebras (esp groupoids) is the result true?**

One class of groupoids with this property is the class of
groups considered as groupoids.
That is, if ${\mathcal U}(G,\ast)\cong{\mathcal U}(H,\ast)$,
then $(G,\ast)\cong (H,\ast)$.

To see this, assume that $f\colon {\mathcal U}(G,\ast)\to{\mathcal U}(H,\ast)$
is an isomorphism. Then

  1. ${\mathcal U}(G,\ast)$ is a semigroup with unit element
     $\{1_G\}$. Since the unit element
     of a semigroup is a definable element, any isomorphism
     $f\colon {\mathcal U}(G,\ast)\to{\mathcal U}(H,\ast)$
     must satisfy $f(\{1_G\})=\{1_H\}$.
  2. An element $x\in {\mathcal U}(G,\ast)$ is a singleton subset
     of $G$ iff $x$ an invertible element (=unit) of the semigroup ${\mathcal U}(G,\ast)$.
     The set of units of ${\mathcal U}(G,\ast)$ will be mapped
     bijectively onto the set of units of ${\mathcal U}(H,\ast)$ by the isomorphism $f$.
  3. The restriction of $f$
     to the set of units/singletons determines an isomorphism
     from $(G,\ast)$ to $(H,\ast)$. That is, the function
     $f'\colon G\to H$ defined so that $f(\{g\}) = \{f'(g)\}$
     is an isomorphism from $(G,\ast)$ to $(H,\ast)$.